# How to dynamically register dependencies like asp netcore does it with IOption<T>

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

At some point while working with asp netcore i noticed that unlike most cases where you register your dependencies like:

- `services.AddTransient<IService, Service>()`
- `services.AddScoped<IService, Service>()`
- `services.AddSingleton<IService, Service>()`

this process is not necessary when working with `IOption<T>`

Is this a feature of Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection which i am unaware of, or is there just some code down the line doing reflection? (I can't imagine how, since any class can be used for IOptions injection)

To me this seems to be a runtime factory kind of thing instead of some underlying assembly scanning+registration.

If this is a feature of Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection i would love to know how it is called, so i can learn more about it.

### TLDR Question:

Is there a `catch all` factory to build instances for a requested service in `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`?

Comment: Built-in. `T` in `IOptions<TOptions>` tend to be concrete classes and the `IOptions` interface is added as part of configuration module.

Comment: Have you had a chance to go through [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options)

Comment: Note: *`An options class must be non-abstract with a public parameterless constructor`* so initializing the options class is a simple matter of gettin gthe constructor and invoking it.

Comment: @Nkosi i had a look at it yes, which made me question how it works even more. Without ever registering it as `IOptions<MyClass>` i can work with it as if that happened somewhere in the code - but if reflection would be used to register candicates it would have no idea which types need to be registered like that... It honestly boggles my mind how MVC does it.

Comment: They use open generic registration. Check source code here https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/Options/Options/src/OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L23

Comment: @Nkosi open generic registration. cool. never heared of it even though i had plenty cases where that would have been useful. Can you make your comment an answer, since it answers my question just right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options module registers the `IOptions<TOptions>` interface using open generics.

for example, a simple generic interface

```
public interface IMyInterface<T> : where T: class {
    T Value { get; }
}
```

and its implementation

```
public class MyClass<T> : IMyInterface<T> : where T: class {

    public MyClass(IDependency dependency) {
        //...
    }

    public T Value { 
        get {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

can be registered using (generic) open types like

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IMyInterface<>), typeof(MyClass<>));
```

So that when ever a `IMyInterface<SomeClass>` is requested to be resolved, `MyClass<SomeClass>` will be activated. The container resolves `IMyInterface<SomeClass>` by taking advantage of [(generic) open types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#open-and-closed-types), eliminating the need to register every [(generic) constructed type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#constructed-types)

Reference [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)

Comment: bit OT but... : Thanks. Today i learned something new and interesting, i shall abuse it like when i first heared about reflection.

Comment: @Dbl check the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#overview-of-dependency-injection) where they mention it. Scroll down a bit and you'll see mention of open generic type